# Calculated sum of visible areas in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression

I want to view the sum of area of each habitat displayed in the layout. Only the displayed habitats in the viewport. Which expression do I have to use in the textbox? Now I have calculated them manual. Is it possible to automate this?

[image]